# How to restructure the Alfresco Repository

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We are using Alfresco Community Edition 5.0d. Unfortunately the best practices are not followed since beginning. Due to this all the documents are stored in the Repository root folder. This folder now has 800,000  records. This is causing performance issues in application.

After looking at several recommendations for keeping fewer number of files in a folder, we want to move all the existing document in to year wise folders. What is the recommended way to move the documents?

Comment: Code? Rules? CMIS? Loads of options...

Comment: You have 800k documents under a single folder?

Comment: are you using community version?

Comment: @Gagravarr yes there are a lot of options to achieve it. However, all the suggested options failed because I am trying to move 800K documents. Tried everything Java/javascript code, Rules, CMIS all failed due to sheer volume of documents which 800K in my case. Moreover, the point of asking the question was to discuss and achieve the most efficient way. The correct way to solve the problem is via Batch processing( as suggested by tartard in the answer section). I am currently testing my solution and will post the answer after testing.

Comment: @Lista .. unfortunately Yes, I have 800K documents in a single folder. Someone in past was just lazy to organize the documents and dropped everything on root folder. It worked well for more than an year. But now we are not able to scale.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a [BatchProcessor](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/batch/BatchProcessor.html) in Java.
Your implementation of [BatchProcessWorkProvider](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/batch/BatchProcessWorkProvider.html) would get the documents under the repository root folder, and your implementation of [BatchProcessWorker](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/batch/BatchProcessor.BatchProcessWorker.html) would move each document in a date folder (after creating the folder if it doesn't exist).
The batchProcessor could be launched either manually from a [java webscript](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-and-Java.html), either automatically with a [patch](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-patch.html) on startup.

If you choose this method you might have to perform a [full reindex](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr-reindex.html) of Solr after the execution of the batch because I remember of a bug in 5.0 causing a node to be duplicated in Solr indexes after being moved, with one version indexed in its original path and the copy indexed in its new path.
You can try to move a node and search it by name (or whatever way which ensure that you only recover this node) in Share. If you have 2 results for this node then you have the bug.
The full Solr reindex can take a lot of time depending on the number of files you have in the repo and their size.

Comment: Thanks @tartard . I also posted this question on alfresco community and got the same strategy as the suggestion. I have implemented the same and currently testing it. Once tested will post the solution here as well